# FutureBuilder with ListView not showing the received data

Tags: flutter

I am trying to show data from a json String received from remote server.

Here you have the model class:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<AlojamientosRegistradosPropiedadesBBDD>
    alojamientosRegistradosPropiedadesBBDDFromJson(String str) =>
        List<AlojamientosRegistradosPropiedadesBBDD>.from(json
            .decode(str)
            .map((x) => AlojamientosRegistradosPropiedadesBBDD.fromJson(x)));

String alojamientosRegistradosPropiedadesBBDDToJson(
        List<AlojamientosRegistradosPropiedadesBBDD> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class AlojamientosRegistradosPropiedadesBBDD {
  AlojamientosRegistradosPropiedadesBBDD(
      {required this.id,
      required this.id_propiedad,
      required this.id_tipo_alojamiento,
      required this.nombre_espacio,
      required this.nombre_tipo_alojamiento,
      required this.unidades});

  String id;
  String id_propiedad;
  String id_tipo_alojamiento;

  String nombre_espacio;
  String unidades;
  String nombre_tipo_alojamiento;

  factory AlojamientosRegistradosPropiedadesBBDD.fromJson(
          Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      AlojamientosRegistradosPropiedadesBBDD(
        id: json["id"],
        id_propiedad: json["id_propiedad"],
        id_tipo_alojamiento: json[" id_tipo_alojamiento"],
        nombre_espacio: json["nombre_espacio"],
        unidades: json["unidades"],
        nombre_tipo_alojamiento: json["nombre_tipo_alojamiento"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "id_propiedad": id_propiedad,
        "id_tipo_alojamiento": id_tipo_alojamiento,
        "nombre_espacio": nombre_espacio,
        "nombre_tipo_alojamiento": nombre_tipo_alojamiento
      };
}
```

Here you have the class that received the json string data:

```
import '../constantes/constantes.dart';




Future<List<AlojamientosRegistradosPropiedadesBBDD>> fetchAlojamientosRegistradosPropiedadesTodos(String id_propiedad) async {


  String url = Constantes.phpFiles+"recibir_alojamientos_registrados_propiedades.php?propiedad="+id_propiedad;
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  print("RESPUESTA tipos alojamientos propiedad ${id_propiedad} ${response.body}");



  return alojamientosRegistradosPropiedadesBBDDFromJson(response.body);

}
```

And here you have the FutureBuilder with the ListView that should show the data:

```
FutureBuilder(
                    future: fetchAlojamientosRegistradosPropiedadesTodos(
                        widget.propiedad.id),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        List<dynamic>? filteredList = snapshot.data as List;
                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: filteredList.length,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                            AlojamientosRegistradosPropiedadesBBDD alojamiento =
                            filteredList![index];

                            return GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: Card(
                                  elevation: 6,
                                  child: new Container(
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                            children: [
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  "${alojamiento.nombre_tipo_alojamiento}",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 16,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                      FontWeight.bold),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                            children: [
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  "${alojamiento.nombre_espacio}",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 14,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),

                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ));
                          },
                        );
                      }

                      return Text("no hay datos");
                    },
                  ),
```

And now the print output that shows the received json String:

```
RESPUESTA tipos alojamientos propiedad 2 [{"id":"1","id_propiedad":"2","id_tipo_alojamiento":"1","nombre_espacio":"Bungalows Rojos","unidades":"3","nombre_tipo_alojamiento":"Bungalow"}]
```

The issue is that the data are not shown. The app output is always `no hay datos`

Comment: Add a print statement just before ListView.builder() and check if the data is present there. If yes then try to give some color of your Text .

Comment: @Aks, the print statement is not called there

Comment: @Aks, the snapshot is always null

Comment: @Aks, i see snapshot null

Comment: @Aks, I have seen the error, it is in the model class, before; id_tipo_alojamiento: json[" id_tipo_alojamiento"], after id_tipo_alojamiento: json["id_tipo_alojamiento"], there is an extra white space